# Preventing Asymptote Asy Re-compiles Because of Inserted Asy Environments

Tags: asymptote, asy

This posting is a *hail-mary* pass.  The response that I received from the Asymptote forum suggests that there is no easy answer.  I wonder how `pdflatex/asymptote` users have dealt with this problem.

`myfile.tex` has 55 inline `asy` environments.  `pdflatex` consequently has created

```
myfile-1.asy, ..., myfile-55.asy.
```

Applying the `asy` command as I go, there is now

```
myfile-1.pdf, ..., myfile-55.pdf.
```

The **problem** is that if I now insert a new inline `asy` environment between `myfile-42.asy` and `myfile.43.asy`, then `pdflatex` will assign the newly inserted asy environment the name `myfile-43.asy`.

`pdflatex` will then assign the trailing asy environments the names

```
myfile-44.asy, ..., myfile-56.asy.
```

This implies that the trailing asy environments will be out of sync with the existing

```
myfile-43.pdf, ..., myfile-55.pdf.
```

Consequently, the `asy` command will have to be re-applied to each of `myfile-44.asy` through `myfile-56.asy`.  Further, this will have to be done every time a new asy environment is inserted into the middle of `myfile.tex`.

**I want to avoid** having to re-apply the `asy` command against all `*.asy` files that follow the inserted `asy` environment.

The remainder of this post discusses my research/experimentation into this difficulty.

---

I have rejected the `\asyinclude[<options>]{<filename.asy>}` approach, because I only want to have one source file to maintain.  Having to specially name and maintain each individual `*.asy` file is simply too much trouble.

---

My first idea was to look for an Asymptote *basename* configuration variable, that I could alter at various places in `myfile.tex`, via `renewcommand`.  My thinking was that then, pdflatex would generate

`newname-1.asy, ..., newname-13.asy`.

Then, I could apply `asy` **one time** against these files, creating

`newname-1.pdf, ..., newname-13.pdf`.

Apparently, Asymptote does not offer a *basename* configuration variable.

---

In `myfile.tex`, I am already *preambling* `\renewcommand\asydir{asytmp}%`, which works well.  One idea is to create the additional subdirectory `asytmpX`, and insert `\renewcommand\asydir{asytmpX}%` at the appropriate place in `myfile.tex`.  Experimenting, this approach is problematic, because inside the `asytmpX` subdirectory, `pdflatex` then creates

```
myfile-43.asy, myfile-44.asy, ..., myfile-55.asy,
```

instead of

```
myfile-1.asy, myfile-2.asy, ..., myfile-13.asy.
```

Apparently, Asymptote's internal `asy` environment counter is **tex-filename-specific**, rather than **subdirectory-specific**.  This approach would therefore require that (to avoid re-applying `asy`) I would have to **rename**

```
myfile-43.pdf, ..., myfile-55.pdf
```

into

```
myfile-44.pdf,..., myfile-56.pdf.
```

---

I then googled : "pdflatex combining tex files".  The idea is to have a separate tex file for each chapter, (or at least a separate file for my appendix to `myfile.tex`), and convert the difficulty from an *Asymptote challenge* into a *pdflatex challenge*.

Exploring, I have rejected `pdfpages`, because I want the overall table of contents and page numbering to be seamless.

I started to explore such ideas as the `docmute` package, and then stopped, because I realized that I was blundering in the dark.  For example, the use of `docmute` will apparently involve a *global application* of pdflatex against the consolidated tex files.

Therefore, I don't see how such an approach avoids my difficulty.

I can't be the first pdflatex/Asymptote user to grapple with this issue.  It is probably not a good idea for me to try to *re-invent the wheel*.  I would like to know how other pdflatex/Asymptote uses have handled this.

Alternatively, perhaps someone with in-depth pdflatex knowledge can weigh in here.

Comment: Instead of naming each file like `myfile-<index>.asy`, you could save each file like `myfile-<md5>.asy`. Probably the easiest way to do so would be to define your own `asymptote` environment from scratch using either [`scontents`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scontents), [`savenv`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/saveenv), or [`filecontentsdef`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/filecontentsdef). This shouldn't be _too_ challenging to implement, although it wouldn't be terribly easy either.

Comment: What you would do is define an `asymptote` environment that saves its contents to a macro. You would define the environment so that at the end it (1) calculates the MD5 sum of its contents using `\pdfmdfivesum`, (2) writes it to a file called `myfile-<md5>.asy`, (3) if a file with the name of `myfile-<md5>.pdf` exists, includes it using `\includegraphics`, and (4) writes a warning to the terminal if the PDF cannot be found. All that you would need to code would be the environment definitions; you shouldn't need to modify your document to manually pick names or add any additional lines.

Comment: @MaxChernoff I just deleted my rebuttal comments.  This is a very promising idea, thanks.